# SourceTree: How to create multiple hotfix branches with Git Flow

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow, hotfix

How can I create a second hotfix branch in Sourcetree when one already exists? Whenever I try to it tells me to finish my current hotfix first. Any way to have multiple hotfix branches?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ok figured it out. Sourcetree by default  doesn't allow you to create more than one hotfix branch at a time using their UI/Git Flow. It wants you to "Git Flow > Finish" the first one before making a new one.

But you can create a second hotfix anyways...

**Permanent solution for this repository**

1. in Sourcetree click Terminal
2. `git config --add gitflow.multi-hotfix true`

Now you can as per usual:
Git Flow > Start New Hotfix

**Temporary solution (allow it just this one time)**

1. in Sourcetree click Terminal
2. `git checkout -b hotfix/my_new_hotfix master`

Now you have a new hotfix named my_new_hotfix

Answer (score 6):

This command will allow it:

`git config --global gitflow.multi-hotfix true`

Comment: Sorry it should have been git config --global gitflow.multi-hotfix true       There should not have been a word "set".   Also, note that if you want for all your configs you use --global.    Otherwise it will apply only to the current repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually edit your git config then it should look like this:

```
[gitflow]
    multi-hotfix = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple hotfixes if you push your first one and delete it locally.  You can then pull it back down again after creating the new one.